# Jquery setting the border-left property

Tags: jquery, css, border

I am using jquery css() function to edit the border-left of an element. My code

```
$('.fc-event').css({
    "border-left":"4px solid "+color
});
```

But when I inspect the element I found out that it sets the color to all border and border-left only to 4px and solid

```
element.style {
    border-color: rgb(186, 67, 67);
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Because they are the underlying CSS properties. `border-left`, `border-right`, `border` etc. are all shortcuts.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: That's an *answer*. :-) `@Apostolos`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-shorthand-properties

Comment: How can I use css() then to set the border left only?

Comment: OP for me works fine .... the problem can be how is your `var  color` check this http://jsfiddle.net/z1qL8xxa/

Comment: @Apostolos that's what you are doing

Comment: maybe something is wrong with my code....unless because I am trying to change the colors of the events rendered by fullcalendar something is done by the fullcalendar plugin which i am missing